# Probability of occurrence based on historical data

Tags: python, probability-density

[image]

The dataset is of occurrence of particular insects in a location for the given year and month. This is available for about 30 years. Now when I give a random location and year, month of future, I want what is the probability of finding that insects in that place based on the historic data.

I tried to to classification problem by labelling all available data as 1. And wanted to check the probability of new data point being label 1 . But the error was thrown as there should be at least two classes to train.

The data looks like this:The x and y are longitude and latitude

```
x         y      year    month
17.01    22.87    2013    01
42.32.   33.09    2015    12
```

Comment: What was the Python code that generated the error?

Comment: You have presented us with just a location and a year/month - what about the type of insect, and their amount? Do you also have those, and if so, could you make those available to us?

Comment: Thank you for the reply...The type of insect is actually a locust ..At one data point ,one locust has been spotted

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. As it appears, your problem is not in the programming part, but actually about the statistical algorithm to estimate probability from point samples. You would be better off at our sister site, Cross Validated, at stats.stackexchange.com. As for your question, I'd start with something very simple, like a Kernel Density Estimator (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity), but you would find better answers there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Think about the problem as a map. You'll need a map for each time period you're interested in, so sum all the occurrences in each month and year for each location. Unless the locations are already binned, you'll need to use some binning as otherwise it is pretty meaningless. So round the values in x and y to a reasonable precision level or use numpy to bin the data. Then you can create a map with the counts/ use a markov model to predict the occurrence.
The reason you're not getting anywhere at the moment is that the chance of finding an insect at any random point is virtually 0.

Comment: Hey,Thank you for the reply. But there are so many locations here as seen in picture(x,y)..I am expecting to give this data set to a algorithm which analyses the dataset monthly wise. For example , for years 2012-2017 ,in the month of October , the locusts are spotted around (20-30,50-60).....and when I give a data point of (25,45,2018,10)...The output should be of probability like 0.85 ...And if I give a data point (35,65,2018,10),the output should be like 0.15...means probability is low ...Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to pass the location you inquire about through the same function you used for binning / check what bin it falls into, then it will get you the corresponding value. (In the example you use rounding to tens) 

To go from frequency to probabilities, the first step would be to look at the number of occurrences in a certain area  compared to the rest of the areas in a given month. Then you can look at building a more complex model.

Comment: Thank you,It certainly gave me a idea ...Rest ,I need to build up on your given idea